# how can i add Multiple hotkey? like f1 f2 f3

Tags: c#

i dont understand     :  Keys key = (Keys)(((int)m.LParam >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
KeyModifier modifier = (KeyModifier)((int)m.LParam & 0xFFFF);

in this code add only  one hotkey and how can i add  Multiple hotkey? like f1 f2 f3。。。。

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
 
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

    enum KeyModifier
    {
        None = 0,
        Alt = 1,
        Control = 2,
        Shift = 4,
        WinKey = 8
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int id = 0;    

        RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, id, 0, Keys.F2.GetHashCode());
        


    }

 protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        if (m.Msg == 0x0312)
        {
        

            Keys key = (Keys)(((int)m.LParam >> 16) & 0xFFFF);             
            KeyModifier modifier = (KeyModifier)((int)m.LParam & 0xFFFF);       
            int id = m.WParam.ToInt32();                                       


            MessageBox.Show("Hotkey has been pressed!");
          
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, thats the first time I've seen anyone use GetHashCode() to hack/convert an int based enum into being an int.. You're allowed to cast it, btw! How to add multiple keys? Have you tried calling RegisterHotkey more than once? Or did you mean you want to press f1 and f2 and f3 simultaneously to activate your code?

Comment: i want add f1 f2 to activate another  function, like f1 delete file  ,f2 copy file ...

Comment: make more hotkey to active more act

Comment: *"Have you tried calling RegisterHotkey more than once?"*